# How to limit the loop so it only loops through for each value once

Tags: bash

Two arrays obtained using:

`array1=($(ls -lad */ | awk '{print $5}'))`

`array2=($(ls -lad */ | awk '{print $9}'))`

Two array typsets:

`declare -a array1='([0]="4096" [1]="4096" [2]="4096" [3]="4096" [4]="4096" [5]="4096" [6]="4096" [7]="4096" [8]="4096")'`

`declare -a array2='([0]="bod/" [1]="working/" [2]="firm/" [3]="symbol/" [4]="info/" [5]="scripts/" [6]="development/" [7]="design/" [8]="testing/")'`

For the file sizes that are less than 10000 it will get the path for these directory names and create full path to be used in an `ls lRa` command where it lists the directories recursively where they directory size is less than 10000.

I currently have 8 file sizes for 8 directory names that are less than 10000 in size at the current level and instead of just printing the path for each directory name once it is doing 8 times. I assume its because I have configured my for loop wrong.

```
for s in ${!array1[*]} 
do
    if [ ${array1[$s]} -lt 10000 ]
    then 
        for dir in ${!array2[@]} 
        do
            paths=$(pwd {array2[$dir]}) 
            echo "$paths/${array2[$dir]}"
        done  
    else
        :
    fi 
done
```

**I HAVE EDITED MY QUESTION:**

I want to create a script that given a path i.e. `/a/path/to/use` it will call `ls -lRa` from this path.

However, the ls -lRa should only be called on directories and their sub-directories if their size is less than 10000 bytes.

For example, if `/a/path/to/use` contains 4 directories with sizes 4096,4096,12480,24620 it would only call ls -lRa on the first two with the last two being ignored.

Once the ls command has been called it will then do the same for any dirs in that directory and so on until it has inspected all dirs in the file structure from the original path.

My attempt above does not appear to be working but provides some explanation as to what I am attempting.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: I don't see how else I can call ```ls -lRa``` but ensure that is skips any dir that has a file size over 10000 bytes. So effectively, it will only list the contents of directories that are less than 10000 bytes and then it will recursively look in those dirs and list any dirs that are less than 10000 bytes and ignore the ones that aren't and so on.

Comment: @Cyrus I have added your "@'

Comment: @bashprofile84 You're going down the wrong path, you should ***never*** parse the output of `ls`.  Rather than asking how to fix your broken implementation, I would instead give the problem you are trying to solve with details.  The best solution is likely to look very different from what you are doing.   Desired output from desired input is the best way to do this.

Comment: @SiegeX, I have edited my question now

Comment: update the question with details on how the arrays were populated (better yet, provide samples of the contents of both arrays, eg, `typeset -p array1; typeset -p array2`; for the inner loop you're looping through the entire `arrray2` array ... don't you want to limit yourself to the `array2` entry that matches the `array1` entry you're currently processing?

Comment: @markp-fuso I have updated the question to contain what you asked for

Answer (score 0):

This will run `ls -la` on any dir/subdir under the current directory that is larger than `minSize` bytes.  Because we are parsing the output of `find` using NULL as the delimiter, it is safe from the pitfalls that plague `ls`.

Note: Because `find` is recursive in nature, we do ***not*** need to run `ls` recursively

```
#!/bin/bash

unset IFS
minSize=10000

while read -r -d $'\0' size dir; do
  if (( size < minSize )); then
    echo "############## $dir ##############"
    ls -la "$dir"
  fi
done < <(find . -mindepth 1 -depth -type d -exec du -b0 {} +)
```

Comment: I tried out this method and it seems to hang for eternity and I am only testing it on the level before the last so it isn't because it is taking time to go through multiple levels.. do you know why this is ?

Comment: Ensure `find . -mindepth 1 -depth -type d -exec du -b {} +` outputs valid directories.  This is what the loop will be processing.  I removed the `-0` option so that its readable

Comment: I ensured that the find command outputs valid dirs and it did in some cases and then in other case it didn't.. I am yet to get an output from the loop itself. It currently just hangs

Comment: It doesn't appear to be working as intended.. it is currently ls each dir twice and is going into dirs that are greater than 10000 when it shouldn't

Comment: Look at the results of the `find` without the loop. Next modify the loop: remove the if-block and add `echo "(Size ${size}) ${dir}"`. Is this still showing all dirs twice?

Comment: @WalterA Just ran the find without loop and it is listing each path 2 times.. so it appears the find command is what is causing the error.. I'm not sure what exactly though. The location I am testing has 2 levels starting in first level and then going to final 2nd level where on the path it appends the subdir with a number but the subdir doesn't contain a number in its name

Comment: @bashprofile84 I don't see what is happening. Work-around is `... du -b0 {} + | sort -u)` but you should be able to have your find statement returning each entry once. Good luck!

Comment: @WalterA Well the solution provided by SiegeX isn't working regardless of it displaying the paths twice as it is listing dirs with a size greater than 10000

Comment: @SiegeX your solution goes through each directory twice one by one listing all directory paths twice and then on the second time it only lists each path once. It then proceeds to go through directories that have a size greater than 10000.

Comment: @bashprofile84 put the output of `tree .` on a pastebin-like site as well as the output of `find . -mindepth 1 -depth -type d -exec du -b {} +`

Comment: @SiegeX I don't have tree installed

Answer (score 0):

With

```
for dir in ${!array2[@]}
```

you will loop through all elements of array2. 
You are already looping through the elements with

```
for s in ${!array1[*]}
```

You do not need the second for loop.
(off-topic: You do not need `$`for an array index, the `pwd` construction is not needed)

```
for s in ${!array1[*]} 
do
    if [ ${array1[s]} -lt 10000 ]
    then 
       echo "$PWD/${array2[s]}"
    fi 
done
```

When you understand this answer, take another look to your implementation of the answer of @SiegeX. I think you added an extra for-loop causing the problem.
His suggestion avoids parsing `ls` and use of arrays.

Comment: @SiegeX answer is not working as intended.. it is listing the contents of the directories twice in all cases and is including dirs that are over 10000 in size